# How to test older webkit with playwright?

Tags: safari, webkit, playwright

I'm testing my application's frontend behavior in multi-browser and multi-version environment. I chose playwright because it supports those environments.

Now, I'm trying to test older versions of webkit. For that, I need to install the older versions first. However, I cannot find the older versions of webkit, and also current version.

Playwright's doc says that they are currently using "WebKit 17.0", but there is no such thing as 'Webkit 17.0'.

I looked up webkit release archives, but I couldn't find any "17.0".

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5795

Comment: i believe this answer your question

Comment: currently the lastest should be 175

Comment: Thank you for sharing the issue. Maybe they are defining certain webkit commit range as "WebKit version."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no much information about webkit versioning, but according to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5795), the "WebKit version" in playwright means the **Version value from Safari's user-agent**.
The contributer says that "version" corresponds to the version currently used in Safari Techonology Preview, and [release Notes for Safari Technology Preview](https://webkit.org/blog/11555/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-121/) says it covers certain range of webkit revisions.

I guess I should build it myself if I want to test older version of webkit,
or I can install multiple versions of playwright.